# What is best approach to remove duplicate values from an array in native javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in javascript like this

```
var arr = [1,2,1.5,3,1.5,1];
```

I want to remove all duplicate values from the array,So my output will be like

```
[2,3]
```

I can do it using loops.I have posted this question here because I need a fasted way to get it done.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure if its the *best approach* but you could use a set: `console.log([...new Set(arr)])`

Comment: @Luke that is not a duplicate since OP wants to get only the values that occurs once instead of getting the unique values

Comment: @Andreas you are right dear

Comment: @Andreas ah yes, you are correct!

Comment: i don't know why people are down voting this

Comment: A valid (and often used) downvote reason is "The question shows no research effort". You did not show visible effort to come up with a solution yourself, by means of a code sample or by linking to similar questions that have not helped you.

Comment: Dear @peterB if you read question i have also mentioned : I can do it using loops.I have posted this question here because I need a fasted way to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this new approach to get only non-repeated values using just `Array.filter`... Fellow users comments are welcome if you feel it's better performance wise or not.

```js
var arr = [1,2,1.5,3,1.5,1]

let tmp = {}
let res = [...arr, ...arr].filter((d, i) => {
  tmp[d] = (tmp[d] || 0) + 1
  return i > arr.length - 1 && tmp[d] == 2
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: that is just an approach to try to get a single loop solution, which is not, because of the doubeling of the items and the late use if the filtering for the second half of the new array, while you use the first to count the items. it looks more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 8):

You could check the first and last index of the value and take it if the index is the same.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 1],
    ones = array.filter((v, _, a) => a.indexOf(v) === a.lastIndexOf(v));

console.log(ones);
```

An approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

> It works with a map by taking the opposite of the check if the map has already one entry with the given value.
>
> For any following same values, the entry changes to `false`, which later omits these values.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 1, 1, 1],
    map = array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, !m.has(v)), new Map),
    ones = array.filter(Map.prototype.get, map);

console.log(ones);
console.log([...map]); // just for checking the values
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using JavaScripts **.filter()** method.

```
const arr = [1,2,1.5,3,1.5,1];

const newArr = arr.filter(val => (arr.filter(v => v === val).length === 1));

console.log(newArr); // [ 2, 3 ]
```